# How to capture screenshot from full screen 3D games in C#

Tags: c#, fullscreen, capture

I am developing an application that requires capturing screenshots of fullscreen games (e.g crossfire) I already have thoroughly researched throughout the internet and still no luck.

I humbly request not to put this inquiry down like my previous ones so that I can finally get this problem solved.

IN C#..

This is not a duplicate. Other threads does not answer my inquiry

Comment: In C#..............

Comment: Not possible. Consider native Windows c-style APIs can be called via p-invoke.  DirectX is COM and is easy to call from c#